# Asana api: Alternative to using API key for authentication?

Tags: api, asana

Is authentication using the API key the only way available to third party developers using the Asana API?

Is there any endpoint that returns the API key, when the user provides his basic login details? Eg: on Heroku, POST http://api.heroku.com/login with username and password params returns the api key.

Such a feature would help simplify login, as it would be an extra step for the user to copy his api key and enter it in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I work for Asana)

No, there is currently no other mechanism. However, we look forward to providing future means of integration, including OAuth.

Comment: Any update on this, Greg? I was about to ask that same question and came across this. Any way to use the currently logged in user?

Comment: Not at the moment. OAuth is in development but I can't provide a release date at this time.